# Can you use mascarpone in place of ricotta?

Tags: substitutions, cheese

Can you substitute mascarpone for ricotta cheese?

Comment: In general, or for a recipe or type of recipe?

Answer (score 6):

Welcome! You absolutely can substitute mascarpone for ricotta. I do it all the time with lasagna, pizza, etc. as many people don't like the texture of ricotta. I do add a *pinch* of salt to the mascarpone.

Comment: another thing that you can try if your guests don't like the texture of ricotta is pass it through a sieve, twice if necessary, as it removes a lot of the grittiness

Answer (score 5):

In a pinch, yes. They're both soft cheeses with a delicate flavour and an Italian name, but they have significant differences you should be aware of before attempting a substitution:

- Ricotta contains a lot more water than mascarpone (feels lighter)
- Mascarpone contains a lot more fat than ricotta (feels heavier, richer)
- Ricotta has more carbohydrates (feels sweeter)
- The composition of the protein and carbohydrate part is very different, though this will be less noticeable

I would be especially wary of this substitution where ricotta is presented "by itself" - in recipes such as cannoli, cassata, pastiera the substitution will not work well.